# Biblatex - idemtracker does not work as expected

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

The `idemtracker` does not work as expected when several works by the same author are cited in a row.
This is what I get:

[image]

I would have expected to get :

`MIT. "Bla bla 2020"`
`Idem, "Bla bla 2018"`
`Idem, "Bla bla 2019"`
`Idem, "Bla bla 2018"`

There is no such problem in the bibliography, where Biblatex correctly detects that it is the same author three times.

[image]

Is there a way to change the behaviour of Biblatex to achieve the desired result?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad1, idemtracker=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Online{MIT2020,
  author = {MIT},
  url = {blablabla.com},
  title = {Bla bla 2020},
}
@Online{MIT2019,
  author = {MIT},
  url = {blablabla.com},
  title = {Bla bla 2019},
}
@Online{MIT2018,
  author = {MIT},
  url = {blablabla.com},
  title = {Bla bla 2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcite{MIT2020}
\footcite{MIT2018}
\footcite{MIT2019}
\footcite{MIT2018}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: the style verbose-trad1 always prints an entry in full the first time it is cited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike says in the comments, `verbose-trad1` prints a full citation for first citations and those don't come with an option to use *idem*.

Here is a way to enable *idem* also for first citations. The idea is to add an `\ifciteidem` test into the bibmacros for `author`, `editor` and `translator`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad1, idemtracker=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifcitation} and test {\ifciteidem}}
          {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
          {\printnames{author}}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifcitation} and test {\ifciteidem}}
          {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
          {\printnames{editor}}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifcitation} and test {\ifciteidem}}
          {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
          {\printnames{translator}}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{MIT2020,
  author = {MIT},
  url    = {blablabla.com},
  title  = {Bla bla 2020},
}
@online{MIT2019,
  author = {MIT},
  url    = {blablabla.com},
  title  = {Bla bla 2019},
}
@online{MIT2018,
  author = {MIT},
  url    = {blablabla.com},
  title  = {Bla bla 2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{MIT2020}
ipsum\autocite{MIT2018}
dolor\autocite{MIT2019}
sit\autocite{MIT2018}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 MIT. Bla bla 2020. url: blablabla.com. 2 Idem. Bla bla 2018. url: blablabla.com. 3 Idem. Bla bla 2019. url: blablabla.com. 4 Idem, Bla bla 2018.]

---

The following approach is slightly more modular

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad1, idemtracker=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro{ifrepeatauthor}{\ifciteidem}
\newbibmacro{repeatedauthor}{%
  \bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewbibmacro{ifrepeatauthor}{\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}}%
  \renewbibmacro{repeatedauthor}{\bibnamedash}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{ifrepeatauthor}
       {\usebibmacro{repeatedauthor}}
       {\printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{ifrepeatauthor}
       {\usebibmacro{repeatedauthor}}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{ifrepeatauthor}
       {\usebibmacro{repeatedauthor}}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{MIT2020,
  author = {MIT},
  url    = {blablabla.com},
  title  = {Bla bla 2020},
}
@online{MIT2019,
  author = {MIT},
  url    = {blablabla.com},
  title  = {Bla bla 2019},
}
@online{MIT2018,
  author = {MIT},
  url    = {blablabla.com},
  title  = {Bla bla 2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{MIT2020}
ipsum\autocite{MIT2018}
dolor\autocite{MIT2019}
sit\autocite{MIT2018}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```