I am using bibLatex-philosophy and I would like to create a ‘Idem’ when there are many works by the same author in the same footnote
My option is this:
\documentclass[%
structure = collection,
pagelayout = periodical,
version = draft,
parindent = 1em,
fontsize = 11pt,
greekfont = porson,
footnotestyle = hung,
captionstyle = standard,
liststyle = indented,
quotstyle   = center,
quotsize    = small,
maketitlestyle  = standard,
chapstyle   =   parcenter,
chapfont    =   roman,
partstyle   =   parcenter,
subsecnumstyle = roman,
titlefont   = roman,
reverseauthortitle  = true,
authorfont  = italic,
authortitlealign    = center,
headerstyle = authortitlecenter,
headerfont  = italic,
toctitlefont    = roman,
tocauthorfont   = italic,
tocpartfont = roman,
maketitlestyle  = standard
]{suftesi}
    \usepackage[%
        style = philosophy-verbose,
        idemtracker = constrict,
        latinemph = true,
        iviemph = true,
        parentracker =   true,
        backend = biber
    ]{biblatex}
    \begin{filecontents}{\bibana1.bib}
    @book{Soujeole-Le-sacrement,
    author = {Benoît-Dominique de La Soujeole},
    title = {Le sacrement de la communion. Essai d'ecclésiologie fondamentale},
    publisher = {Editions universitaires},
    location = {Paris},
    year = 1998,
    pages = {182-241}}
    @book{Soujeole-Il-sacramento,
    author = {Benoît-Dominique de La Soujeole},
    title = {Il sacramento della comunione. Ecclesiologia fondamentale},
    location = {Casale Monferrato},
    year = 2000,
    pages = {207-279}}
    @book{Soujeole-Introduction,
    author = {Benoît-Dominique de La Soujeole},
    title = {Introduction au mystère de l'Église},
    location = {Paris},
    year = 2006,
    pages = {413-437}}
    @book{Soujeole-Introduction-EN,
    author = {Benoît-Dominique de La Soujeole},
    title = {Introduction to the Mystery of the Church},
    location = {Washington (DC)},
    year = 2014,
    pages = {409-437}}
    @book{Soujeole-Introduccion-ES,
    author = {Benoît-Dominique de La Soujeole},
    title = {Introducci\'on al misterio de la Iglesia},
    location = {Madrid},
    year = 2020,
    pages = {369-392}}
    \end{filecontents}
    \addbibresource{\bibana1.bib}
\begin{document}
... et elle est même devenue dominante dans les années 1970– 
1980\footnote{%
Nous avons étudié cette pénétration en ecclésiologie 
dans les livres suivants: \cite{Soujeole-Le-sacrement} 
(trad. italienne \cite{Soujeole-Il-sacramento}); 
et \cite{Soujeole-Introduction} 
(trad. anglaise \cite{Soujeole-Introduction-EN}; 
trad. espagnole \cite{Soujeole-Introduccion-ES}).
    }. %
\end{document}


welcome! please provide a complete but minimal document we can compile to reproduce your situation. you can use biblatex-examples as a source of bib entries, so you don't have to include those, too. also, please format code by highlighting it and clicking the {} button.

Thank you for your response. This is the first time I have stepped in to ask for help and I do not know how to use the site. How can I post the code with the books mentioned and create a minimum compilable example?

please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that. you can use the edit button at the bottom left of your post to edit the question and add the code.

I pose my question again.

thanks for editing. I've combined the three chunks into one to make it easier for people who want to help to copy everything they need. feel free to revert this if you object.

you don't seem to have any duplicate keys in that footnote, so I'm not sure idem is appropriate in this case. have you considered using more detailed .bib entries, perhaps with the related field? note that I can't understand your text entirely without resorting to google, but Biblatex/Biber can handle the relationships between these entries better if  they are marked up in the data. as far as biblatex knows, these are all distinct publications that just happen to be by the same author.

philosophy-verbose is based on verbose-trad2, for which the solution for verbose-trad1 from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614051/35864 should also work.
